# how to setup payment processors for multiple organiazations on one instance of Civi? for franchise type locations

Tags: payment-processor

are there any extensions or alternative instructions for setting up and connecting the payment processors of civi to multiple organizations within one instance of civi? For events and memberships we have multiple locations that need to collect their own fees - franchise type setup. It makes sense to add the same account type fields needed in custom field sets for each type of processor, however, for event and memberships are there any extensions or other instructions to select proper location for each possibility and have payment go to that location directly and not our HQ organization?  thanks much!

---additionally, we are using STRIPE and Paypal

Comment: Are you wanting the Payment Processor to deliver funds in to a different bank account for each chapter

Comment: Yes, each chapter of the organization has its own accounts that funds need to go to directly.  There are also a few use cases where chapter and HQ organization wish to split fees, but majority of the processing is directly with each branch chapter.

Comment: Hello again, petednz or anyone else, just looking for a followup on this issue.  I have most of my needs taken care of, however, this piece is something that I haven't been able to figure out yet, but still very critical to our overall project. 
---What is the best way to setup payment accounts for multiple organizations in one case of Civi, while maintaining the Permissions Relationships format for overall structure?  thanks much!

Comment: If you have 5 orgs - each with their own paypal account and hence with their own payment processor - and you have 5 events, one for each org, and you set each of those events to use the relevant paypal account - then what is the missing feature you need?

Comment: Hi, I been digging more, and originally was looking at main org setup and thought there could only be one account per processor type.  I did then find where to add the additional payment processor accounts - however, is there a way to have those payment processor accounts linked directly to a specific org only?  We will be using the permission relationships so that managers can only work with their direct org, and when they setup events I would like them to be able to select from only their processor accounts and not other org accounts. How can they see only their accounts?

Answer (score 1):

not sure I totally understand but if I do what you want is to setup one "Financial Type" for each chapter and then on each donation page you can select which Financial Type the money will be assigned to. You can also, if necessary, setup multiple payment processors -- one org we work with has 10 different processor accounts and financial types in order to keep chapter funds distinct.

you also might look into the civicrm multisite extension

Comment: Hi, to clarify, yes we would create the "financial type" for each chapter, and each chapter would need its own accounts.  We will be able to limit the payment processors to stripe and paypal for the entire organization, but each chapter is run independently and has its own accounts and processing needs.  I have not looked into the multi site extension as I am very new to CIVI, but would that be the recommended way for each chapter to manage its own branch?  yet at the same time allow our HQ to manage/oversee/track what is happening?

Comment: DJS I think you should ask the question about managing multisite to a separate question or better go find those which already discuss it. Yes multisite is one approach. Permissioned Relationships is another.

Comment: ericG, if you setup multiple payment processors in Civi can they all be linked to the same account with Stripe?